# How to call a function on value change while using ng-selectize?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and I am using this library for select options -
https://github.com/NicholasAzar/ng-selectize

Two-way binding is working but I am not able to call a function when the value is changed.

Here is the code -

signup.component.html

```
<ng2-selectize id="date" class="small" name="date" [config]="singleSelectConfig" [options]="dates" placeholder="Date" [(ngModel)]="model.date" required #date="ngModel" ngDefaultControl (change)="updateDate()">
</ng2-selectize>
```

signup.component.ts

```
DEFAULT_DROPDOWN_CONFIG: any = {
    highlight: false,
    create: false,
    persist: true,
    plugins: ['dropdown_direction', 'remove_button'],
    dropdownDirection: 'down'
};

SINGLE_SELECT_PRESET_VALUE_CONFIG = Object.assign({}, this.DEFAULT_DROPDOWN_CONFIG, {
    labelField: 'value',
    valueField: 'id',
    searchField: ['value']
});

singleSelectConfig: any = this.SINGLE_SELECT_PRESET_VALUE_CONFIG;

updateDate() {
        // call this function
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Please provide it if so!

Comment: no there is no error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngModelChange`:

```
[(ngModel)]="model.date" (ngModelChange)="dateChanged($event)"
```

Where `$event` is the new model. You can also access it via `this.model.date` in the component of course.